# Can I get the additions and subtractions from a specific commit using NodeGit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, npm

I'm trying to replicate the output of `git log --stat` using the npm package nodegit. The docs (http://www.nodegit.org/api/commit/) show a number of different `GET` function on the Commit model but none of then seem to provide the "++ --" stats I'm looking for. Has anyone been able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The Commit model can retrieve an array of Diffs which can then retrieve an array of Patches. The Patch model has a function called `lineStats()` which will return an object containing the following keys and values:

```
{ total_context: 8, total_additions: 11, total_deletions: 12 }
```

Here's a sample:

```
return commit.getDiff().then(function (diffList: any) {
    return Promise.all(diffList.map(function (diff: any) {
        return diff.patches().then(function (patches: any) {
            return Promise.all(patches.map(function (patch: any) {
                console.log('Line Stats: ', patch.lineStats())
            })
        })
    })
})
```